# Overflow hidden is not working on pseudo before and after elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Good day! I am trying to make a shape in css with before and afters. The problem is that the before and afters have an overflow and i want to hide that. When hiding it in de container named shape, it is not possible to do that with overflow-x: hidden and max-width: 100%. Still i am able to scroll in safari, but not in Chrome. Why is this? And how do i fix this? Thanks in advance.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b9m5tpxq/

```
    padding: 0; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}



.shape{
    background-color: red;
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    position: relative;
    height: inherit;
}

.shape p{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.shape::after{
    content:'';
    height:120px;
    width: 120%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3rem;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: -1rem;
    margin-right:-1rem;
}

.shape::before{
    content:'';
    height:120px;
    width: 120%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: -3rem;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: -1rem;
    margin-right: -1rem;
}
```

```
<body>
<div class="shape">
<p>Text</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the shape differently using only background and you won't have any overflow issue:

```css
.box {
  padding:70px 50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top    right,transparent 49.5%,blue  50%) top   ,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,green 50%) bottom,
    red;
  background-size:100% 20px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-bottom:50px solid green;
  border-top:   50px solid blue;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 20px,100% calc(100% - 20px),0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dignissim, ipsum et commodo semper, tellus orci ultricies elit, et volutpat dolor neque ac lectus. Fusce vel enim nulla. Nam a aliquam diam, vel mattis velit. Phasellus egestas suscipit lacus a ornare. Morbi luctus sapien nec metus faucibus rutrum. Integer hendrerit auctor libero, vitae imperdiet quam. Aliquam facilisis aliquam efficitur.

Ut dictum mauris a sagittis eleifend. Maecenas in libero et nibh sollicitudin ultricies. Nunc euismod luctus sapien sed malesuada. Sed eleifend a odio sit amet auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum condimentum tempor. Ut viverra venenatis diam tincidunt condimentum. Morbi vehicula dolor risus, eget sollicitudin ipsum semper venenatis. Nullam sollicitudin non libero sed tincidunt.

Quisque suscipit aliquam ipsum, vel convallis nisl pretium id. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc a magna ullamcorper, commodo nibh vel, venenatis sem. Nullam cursus lobortis diam, eu malesuada elit aliquet a. Vivamus rutrum erat libero, nec congue magna maximus sed. Vestibulum ut orci semper, consectetur ligula et, scelerisque nisl. Nulla sit amet ullamcorper nunc. Sed fringilla elit nec mollis aliquet. Sed tempor leo ac placerat tincidunt. Sed nisl purus, aliquam et fermentum vel, lacinia quis purus. Integer vulputate leo in eros molestie varius. Donec eu ante laoreet arcu eleifend pharetra. Quisque laoreet orci id justo posuere consectetur. Sed sodales tristique erat, nec viverra velit feugiat vel. Fusce quam nibh, pretium at turpis ut, vulputate sollicitudin dui. Fusce vulputate ex vitae dolor auctor efficitur.
</div>
```

and with CSS variable to easily control the shape:

```css
.box {
  --b:50px; /* border width*/
  --a:20px; /* to control the angle (use vw unit to keep the same angle on resize)*/

  padding:calc(50px + var(--a)) 50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top    right,transparent 49.5%,blue  50%) top   ,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49.5%,green 50%) bottom,
    red;
  background-size:100% var(--a);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-bottom:var(--b) solid green;
  border-top:   var(--b) solid blue;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% var(--a),100% calc(100% - var(--a)),0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dignissim, ipsum et commodo semper, tellus orci ultricies elit, et volutpat dolor neque ac lectus. Fusce vel enim nulla. Nam a aliquam diam, vel mattis velit. Phasellus egestas suscipit lacus a ornare. Morbi luctus sapien nec metus faucibus rutrum. Integer hendrerit auctor libero, vitae imperdiet quam. Aliquam facilisis aliquam efficitur.

Ut dictum mauris a sagittis eleifend. Maecenas in libero et nibh sollicitudin ultricies. Nunc euismod luctus sapien sed malesuada. Sed eleifend a odio sit amet auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum condimentum tempor. Ut viverra venenatis diam tincidunt condimentum. Morbi vehicula dolor risus, eget sollicitudin ipsum semper venenatis. Nullam sollicitudin non libero sed tincidunt.

Quisque suscipit aliquam ipsum, vel convallis nisl pretium id. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc a magna ullamcorper, commodo nibh vel, venenatis sem. Nullam cursus lobortis diam, eu malesuada elit aliquet a. Vivamus rutrum erat libero, nec congue magna maximus sed. Vestibulum ut orci semper, consectetur ligula et, scelerisque nisl. Nulla sit amet ullamcorper nunc. Sed fringilla elit nec mollis aliquet. Sed tempor leo ac placerat tincidunt. Sed nisl purus, aliquam et fermentum vel, lacinia quis purus. Integer vulputate leo in eros molestie varius. Donec eu ante laoreet arcu eleifend pharetra. Quisque laoreet orci id justo posuere consectetur. Sed sodales tristique erat, nec viverra velit feugiat vel. Fusce quam nibh, pretium at turpis ut, vulputate sollicitudin dui. Fusce vulputate ex vitae dolor auctor efficitur.
</div>

<div class="box" style="--a:5vw;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dignissim, ipsum et commodo semper, tellus orci ultricies elit, et volutpat dolor neque ac lectus. Fusce vel enim nulla. Nam a aliquam diam, vel mattis velit. Phasellus egestas suscipit lacus a ornare. Morbi luctus sapien nec metus faucibus rutrum. Integer hendrerit auctor libero, vitae imperdiet quam. Aliquam facilisis aliquam efficitur.

Ut dictum mauris a sagittis eleifend. Maecenas in libero et nibh sollicitudin ultricies. Nunc euismod luctus sapien sed malesuada. Sed eleifend a odio sit amet auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum condimentum tempor. Ut viverra venenatis diam tincidunt condimentum. Morbi vehicula dolor risus, eget sollicitudin ipsum semper venenatis. Nullam sollicitudin non libero sed tincidunt.

Quisque suscipit aliquam ipsum, vel convallis nisl pretium id. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc a magna ullamcorper, commodo nibh vel, venenatis sem. Nullam cursus lobortis diam, eu malesuada elit aliquet a. Vivamus rutrum erat libero, nec congue magna maximus sed. Vestibulum ut orci semper, consectetur ligula et, scelerisque nisl. Nulla sit amet ullamcorper nunc. Sed fringilla elit nec mollis aliquet. Sed tempor leo ac placerat tincidunt. Sed nisl purus, aliquam et fermentum vel, lacinia quis purus. Integer vulputate leo in eros molestie varius. Donec eu ante laoreet arcu eleifend pharetra. Quisque laoreet orci id justo posuere consectetur. Sed sodales tristique erat, nec viverra velit feugiat vel. Fusce quam nibh, pretium at turpis ut, vulputate sollicitudin dui. Fusce vulputate ex vitae dolor auctor efficitur.
</div>

<div class="box" style="--a:80px;--b:5px">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dignissim, ipsum et commodo semper, tellus orci ultricies elit, et volutpat dolor neque ac lectus. Fusce vel enim nulla. Nam a aliquam diam, vel mattis velit. Phasellus egestas suscipit lacus a ornare. Morbi luctus sapien nec metus faucibus rutrum. Integer hendrerit auctor libero, vitae imperdiet quam. Aliquam facilisis aliquam efficitur.

Ut dictum mauris a sagittis eleifend. Maecenas in libero et nibh sollicitudin ultricies. Nunc euismod luctus sapien sed malesuada. Sed eleifend a odio sit amet auctor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum condimentum tempor. Ut viverra venenatis diam tincidunt condimentum. Morbi vehicula dolor risus, eget sollicitudin ipsum semper venenatis. Nullam sollicitudin non libero sed tincidunt.

Quisque suscipit aliquam ipsum, vel convallis nisl pretium id. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc a magna ullamcorper, commodo nibh vel, venenatis sem. Nullam cursus lobortis diam, eu malesuada elit aliquet a. Vivamus rutrum erat libero, nec congue magna maximus sed. Vestibulum ut orci semper, consectetur ligula et, scelerisque nisl. Nulla sit amet ullamcorper nunc. Sed fringilla elit nec mollis aliquet. Sed tempor leo ac placerat tincidunt. Sed nisl purus, aliquam et fermentum vel, lacinia quis purus. Integer vulputate leo in eros molestie varius. Donec eu ante laoreet arcu eleifend pharetra. Quisque laoreet orci id justo posuere consectetur. Sed sodales tristique erat, nec viverra velit feugiat vel. Fusce quam nibh, pretium at turpis ut, vulputate sollicitudin dui. Fusce vulputate ex vitae dolor auctor efficitur.
</div>
```

Comment: Wow you are helping me so much right now! Thank you so so much. I was also thinking about this but i never figured out how to do this correctly. And is it also possible to add a border of 1 or 2 px black to the top and bottom of the blue and green shape?

Comment: @Dehv27 with what I have done propably it would difficult to add the border. Will think about another idea. By the way you can have this as a separate question since it's out of the scope of this one. Another question can be more helpful for you and other.

Comment: Oke, i will do that, but for now, so much thank for your help already. This is awesome :)

Comment: @Dehv27 welcome, don't forget to upvote/accept the answer if it solves your issue